# What is the name of this screwhead?

Tags: repair

This is too weird to describe. (See below) What kind of driver will fit this screwhead?

[image]

Comment: where is the screw used?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the screw at an angle, so we can better understand how it's shaped? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a tire lug screw.  You could try a multi grip universal socket like the one below depending on the actual size of you screw.

[image]

What I usually do in cases like this is get out my Dremel tool with a cutoff disk and grind a slot in the middle of the screw and then use a large screwdriver to undo it. When that hasn't worked, I pounded a copper pipe close in size into the screw and made a makeshift socket, flattened the pipe and used an adjustable wrench to turn it out.

Comment: I have one of those and have never used it but it might work. It is a tamper proof screw that I don’t know if I have seen before it’s not a torx but close I would find a Tamper proof bit set on line and find one that looks the same OR use a multi socket OR Dremel as jack mentioned.